# I am stepping down as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I will be stepping down as a mod from Chem.SE at the end of the month.

I greatly enjoyed [cleaning up old questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3444/402), [getting popular questions answered](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/20-most-viewed-questions-that-need-answers-updated-29-jun-2022), and [bringing more traffic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3526/402) to Chem.SE which were my primary goals as a moderator.

That said, I have learned a lot while being a member here and hope for more growth for the site in the future.

I invite anyone to find me on LinkedIn. I think I'm the only Melanie Shebel so I'm easy to find.

Comment: You did great and best of success in the future! This stack exchange has had great moderators and you did your share quietly and effectively!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your service to the community.

One good thing is that in regards to:

> "I greatly enjoyed cleaning up old questions, getting popular questions answered, and bringing more traffic to Chem.SE which were my primary goals as a moderator."

all those things can be done without a diamond. So stepping down wouldn't have a huge impact on your "goals as a mod". However I also totally understand if those are things that you no longer enjoy doing.

I'm curious to learn more about the drop in interest from the members of your FB group, which you mentioned recently on a comment to one of my posts, but that's not so important here.

Thanks so much again!

Comment: I believe their questions get downvoted to oblivion and feel this site is for PhDs only.

Comment: I sympathize with you about downvotes. I don't believe in downvoting at all on the main site (Meta is different). On Chem.SE I've upvoted more than 100x more than downvoted!! My 3 downvotes must have been ages ago because I now have a no-downvote policy. On MMSE, I've voted 4000+ times and never once downvoted!

Comment: @BuckThorn and everyone: Could we discuss down-voting in chat? I chose a chat rather than a meta-post because rather than having answers, it seems we would benefit from a discussion. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138453/downvoting

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138472/discussion-on-answer-by-user1271772-i-am-stepping-down-as-a-moderator).