# Feature request on asking a user for the reason on downvoting a question

Tags: support, feature-request, down-votes

Wouldn't it be legit for an OP to know why his posts are getting downvoted, Wouldn't it be great if the user submits a reason when downvoting, This would both the user to improve and for the mod to check if the reason provided is legit or not,

Most the users who downvote don't comment, It would be better if a feature is installed asking for the reason when downvoted

I am requesting this feature because today I have asked 2 questions which I feel is completely reasonable to ask, One of my previous question was also downvoted, How is it every question of mine is against the stack exchange rules?

[What kind of solution is formed when alkali metals are dissolved in a high concentration of liquid ammonia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167580/what-kind-of-solution-is-formed-when-alkali-metals-are-dissolved-in-a-high-conce)

[Regarding interstitial carbides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/regarding-interstitial-carbides)

I have even asked in the comments on the reason of downvotes, But there wasn't any reply I feel there's an habitual downvoter ( maybe I am wrong ). So wouldn't it be needful if such an feature is installed?

Comment: You would not be the first to think that would be a good idea, but there are various reasons why such a change is unlikely to happen. You might regard anonymity as a built-in feature of the system, at least for the SE mortals (which includes mods - we can see a little more of what's going on, but you'd prob be disappointed about how much that is). Also, there are algorithms that are intended to check whether a rogue user is voting in a systematic manner, for instance targeting a specific person. This allows  detection of cheating (cooperative voting, sockpuppets etc) as well.

Comment: Finally, rem to interpret downvoting on this site as what the blurb on the up/down arrows states: a statement of whether the voter thinks the post is *useful*, perhaps to them, but ideally to the community at large. The site seeks to accumulate useful Q&As but avoid repetition, for instance. In any case, this comment is not a complete answer. You can check for similar questions on meta. I will do so later unless another mod beats me to it.

Comment: I don't get you still @BuckThorn

Comment: Regarding why no one replied to your request for an explanation: in your case, one or two people, of 18 or 19 visitors, downvoted. Those visitors are unlikely to revisit your question, so would never see your comment. Meta is the right place to complain. You can also raise a flag, but hopefully you will understand that the issue with voting is unlikely to be resolved by structural means (changes to the site).

Comment: I don't find the people who downvoted tell the reason but other visitors justifying the downvote saying this question doesn't have enough research, But I have also showed questions which has answers in books and web and also high upvotes, I have taken help of enough resources and have posted my question, Still I get downvotes in all the posts I get, I don't feel it right

Comment: Isn't my question clear enough, what else should I improve in the above question @BuckThorn I have got a downvote even in this question :(

Comment: This is an ongoing dilemma on the site. I won't write more on why now. For the time being or until someone else comments or answers, please see related posts: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+downvotes

Comment: @BuckThorn Will you please check if the downvotes I got are from one single person or not, Please check only that, Please...

Comment: I can't check that. Please see my earlier comments: **voting is anonymous**.

Comment: Don't tell me who has done it, Being a mod you can check it for sure right. This question is properly written still I get downvotes in all my posts, Don't you think this is suspicious

Comment: No, that is in fact not possible for mods, as I attempted to explain numerous times.

Comment: But please tell me if I miss something in this question? @BuckThorn

Comment: I edited your post on intercalates (improved grammar). It is not my field of expertise. I would have to spend some time online looking for an answer. Basically I found two main issues with the post: (1) too many questions in one post (2) deficits in grammar and punctuation (of secondary importance, but it impacts how people perceive your post - if they think it sloppy they will wonder why they should pay attention to it). It would help if you read the site guide that explains what posts are considered appropriate.

Comment: Re. *"This would both the user to improve and for the mod to check if the reason provided is legit or not"*: You can't expect moderators to check the validity of every single downvote on the site, that might be a bit much.

Comment: @orthocresol They can check them atleast when a problem arises

Comment: I'm not going to pretend I have read this post, but here is another post that will explain, why this question has gotten that many down-votes. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/260760 Please read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Down-voting is part of the quality-control mechanism. If it weren't anonymous, folks would be less likely to vote, and less likely to vote based on the quality of the post.

The way the rules stand, nothing prevents a user from voting in a manner others don't like. However, there are thousands of users on the site, and so if sufficient individuals use their right to vote (and invest the time to think about the posts), votes will correlate with quality.

For specific questions, the vote tally might not reflect the quality of the post (e.g. if the post gets improved by editing after some votes were made, or if the post triggers an intense reaction in some, unbeknownst to the individual posing the question). In those cases, it is fine to ask about it on meta, or in the comments, or opening a chat room.

Moderators don't know who votes on which questions. Hi-rep users can look up the number of up-votes and down-votes of other users, though.

Posts on meta are a bit different in terms of votes. If the OP is discussing a possible new feature, a down-vote might show that people are not convinced of the proposal, not that they don't like that it is discussed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to say that your feature request is bad (or good).

However, the feature request to create a requirement for users to comment on a post in order to downvote, would require effort from Stack Exchange's web development team. Feature requests for the web development team to get involved, usually have to first be approved by Stack Exchange's Community Management team (CMs). The CMs will often require there to be consensus on the relevant Meta page in order to even consider such a feature request. For something very specific to Chem.SE like "may we please get the mchem extension to MathJax installed?", this Chem.Meta page might be a relevant Meta page, but your feature request is asking to add code that would affect the way people can downvote, which is something for which the CMs will likely want to get consensus on the [network-wide Meta page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). For this I would ***highly recommend*** that you check Meta.SE to see if others have asked exactly the same question before (i.e. to see whether or not your question would be considered a "duplicate" of someone else's previous question). I think you'll see that people **have tried to suggest your proposal, and failed to gain support.**

Personally [I'm with you](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5202/i-am-stepping-down-as-a-moderator#comment11714_5203), and I've even advocated that on *some sites* we should remove the downvote button all together. On Chem.SE I have upvoted almost 400x more often than I downvoted, and those downvotes were a *long* time ago (since then I have stopped downvoting all together, and on the more recently launched [Matter Modeling Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) I've upvoted 4000+ times and never once downvoted! I've been critical of rampant downvoting in [this Chem.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61769440#61769440).

However, you and I and perhaps [A-Chem](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/66245/achem) are in the minority across the network. Your question may have been better received it was not phrased as a "feature request" but more as just a general discussion about downvoting to check the temperature of what this specific SE community wants, before considering whether or not we would have a chance at convincing the CMs to give the web development team the green lights to implement your proposed feature.

---

Edit: AChem's comment says "Physics, History of Science & Math, and even Mathematics do not have such persistent problems" and I wasn't 100% sure about that since in my experience I've got upvoted a lot better on Chem.SE and Math.SE compared to Physics.SE, and HSM has an Orwell-inspired user who was banned network-wide presumably for excessive downvoting, which is so high in volume that it visibly affects that small site. However I found this interesting today:

A new user asked a question on MMSE which still has 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes:

[image]

Due to the nature of that question, I looked to see their network profile and saw that they'd asked 1 question on Physics.SE, 1 question on Engineering.SE, and 1 question on Chemistry.SE before asking the above question on MMSE.

The Engineering.SE question had essentially no formatting, and no separation into paragraphs, but had a net score of 0:

[image]

The Physics.SE question was similar and also had a net score of 0:

[image]

The Chemistry.SE question was ***also similar***, but thanks to a major edit by andselisk, and advice in the comments from Poutnik, and Nilay Ghosh, it looks ***significantly better*** than any of this user's other questions, and yet the score was -2:

[image]

Therefore, AChem may be right that the downvoting problem is unique to Chemistry (out of these science sites), and I've also observed now that Chemistry.SE users are more helpful than the Physics or Engineering users when it comes to making edits that improve the post, and giving advice about formatting in the comments.

Comment: It is not that I am against downvoting, it is that I am against persistent, habitual downvoting of every new question that is posted. We discussed this issue in chat before and it is only a problem in Chem. *It is not a very welcoming process for new users.* That is it. Physics, History of Science & Math, and even Mathematics do not have such *persistent* problems. Karsten is making genuine efforts to assist new users.

Comment: @AChem Thanks for the clarification :) I totally agree that it's not welcoming to new users. It's also not friendly to experienced users who put immense effort into helping people but still often get downvotes that are not always deserved.

Comment: Your analysis is very interesting.